# git status error while git log and git reflog provide valid responses: bad tree object HEAD

Tags: git

`git log` works fine and provides:

```
commit ac1d9fec39372683cd20fba15f9c5318b957cf25 (HEAD -> master)
Author: TryerGit <Email@Email.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 5 20:17:36 2022

    Writeup per suggestion

commit e6cdf4125529fcb8c0b0e131b12c4ab24012cdfd (origin/master)
Author: TryerGit <Email@Email.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 4 11:54:53 2022

    B4 trying folder specific .gitignore files

commit 54a753a762a7cdfbdea9a0d50deef3b886712cc3
Author: TryerGit <Email@Email.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 26 17:32:24 2022

    Functionally OKAYish version

... and so on
```

`git reflog` works fine and provides:

```
ac1d9fe (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: Writeup per suggestion
e6cdf41 (origin/master) HEAD@{1}: commit: B4 trying folder specific .gitignore files
54a753a HEAD@{2}: commit: Functionally OKAYish version
... and so on
```

However, `git status` gives the error:

`error: bad tree object HEAD`

How can this error be fixed?

---

ETA: `git fsck` says:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2338/2338), done.
error: 6e6758bea668ae2fb6271dec137927981548b581: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
broken link from  commit ac1d9fec39372683cd20fba15f9c5318b957cf25
              to    tree 6e6758bea668ae2fb6271dec137927981548b581
missing tree 6e6758bea668ae2fb6271dec137927981548b581
dangling tree 3771f5b131b8934d28373230375c76658c93c0c8
```

---

ETA2: A cloud based synching mechanism creates folders in `.git/objects/` in case of clash as, say, `fa (2)` if `fa` is currently synching or something along those lines. So, I navigated into the `.git/objects/` folder and renamed `fa (2)` back to `fa`. In case there was both `fa` and `fa (2)` folders present, I navigated into each of these folders and deleted the folder whose contents were older. Then, the remaining folder, I renamed it back to `fa`. After doing this for all folders in `.git/objects/` that had duplicated entries, running `git fsck` returns:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2338/2338), done.
```

and no errors seemingly indicating that all is well. `git status` no longer returns any errors. This may or may not work in your case. Please see torek's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813583/git-status-error-while-git-log-and-git-reflog-provide-valid-responses-bad-tree#comment126905597_71813631)

Comment: What does `git fsck` say?

Comment: @StephenC Updated OP with `git fsck` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of having a bad tree object, namely `6e6758bea668ae2fb6271dec137927981548b581`.  The object itself either does not exist at all, or is invalid internally; the `git fsck` output implies the former.

It's not clear how you got into this situation, but `git log` by itself never notices because it obtains *commit* `ac1d9fec39372683cd20fba15f9c5318b957cf25` which itself is intact.  It's just that this commit *refers to* the missing tree object.  As long as the software never tries to retrieve the missing object, nobody notices that it is missing.  The bad (because-of-missing-tree, but not bad on its own) commit also refers to previous commit `e6cdf4125529fcb8c0b0e131b12c4ab24012cdfd`, which is good all the way around, and all previous commits are fine.

If you can find or re-create the missing tree object, the repository will be restored to usability.  Alternatively, if you can replace the bad commit with a good one that refers to an existing or new tree object, the repository as a whole will be OK, although the stored *snapshot* that went with commit `6e6758bea668ae2fb6271dec137927981548b581` is gone.

Comment: my `.git` folder on different machines gets auto synched via google drive that runs on multiple machines. The above error occurs on one of the 3 machines. It is fine on the other two. Let me force copy the `.git` folder from the working machine to the third machine where it does not work. I got a similar error in the past which was fixed by this manoeuvre. Thanks!

Comment: Never put a repository on a cloud-synced folder, and you've just experienced one of the reasons for that rule: cloud-syncing software will *rename* files on you (or Git)!

Comment: are you saying the entire repo: .git folder, files in the working tree, etc., should be outside of cloud synching? Or only that the .git folder should be outside of cloud synching -- while the working tree files can very well be under cloud synch? In case of the latter, since the .git folder is not synched, then every commit will have to be redone on multiple machines. This is an unnecessary repetition. If you suggest the former case, then, I have a large amount of files / folder under .gitignore. How could I synch these files across machines?

Comment: The working tree could be cloudy; the `.git` should not. For most setups you'd need to use `--separate-git-dir` (or `git worktree add`) to achieve this I think.